# Automatically bookmark all open tabs

Tags: google-chrome, scripting

I was wondering what would be the best way for a script in the background to periodically bookmark all tabs I have open on chrome. I like saving them all periodically and time stamping them as it helps me when I'm doing research. Any ideas? Not looking for a full solution just a helpful point at the right tool for the job would do. I want it to be able to run whilst I'm browsing and not interfere at all. Thanks